# Installs fails with Error Database does not support creation of triggers - User has TRIGGER privilege

Tags: wordpress, installation

MySQL 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 (Ubuntu)
WordPress 5.6
CiviCRM 5.32.2

Attempting a fresh install of WP and CiviCRM on a clean AWS site as upgrading CiviCRM  was continually failing

I get this error:

System Requirements
We are not able to install the software. Please review the errors and warnings below.

Severity    Section Name    Details
Error   Database    CiviCRM MySQL Trigger   Database does not support creation of triggers
Refresh
After updating your system, refresh to test the requirements again.
Environment
The system settings were auto-detected. CiviCRM will be installed with:

CMS Database    mysql://wpdbuser:HIDDEN@localhost/wordpress

CiviCRM Database
mysql://wpdbuser:HIDDEN@localhost/wordpress

CiviCRM Settings File   /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

CiviCRM Source Code /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm

My Wordpress database user has full privileges including TRIGGER.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'wpdbuser'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for wpdbuser@localhost                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `wpdbuser`@`localhost`                    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wordpress`.* TO `wpdbuser`@`localhost` |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I specifically added TRIGGER

```
mysql> GRANT  TRIGGER ON wordpress.* TO 'wpdbuser'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

How can I resolve this ?      Is this a CiviCRM problem or a MySQL issue?

Comment: did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after making the changes?

Comment: Hi Southside, a simular question is asked at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11199/could-not-create-a-database-trigger-on-aws-rds/15624#15624 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not create a database trigger on AWS RDS](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11199/could-not-create-a-database-trigger-on-aws-rds)

Answer (score 4):

In the MySQL CLI, run:

`SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;`

Comment: Thanks for contributing.  This answer was automatically flagged as having a low quality score.  To improve the quality, please explain what this does and why it solves the problem.